# Why are the results of these two expressions different?

Tags: c, gcc

I was developing an answer to another question, and ran into a brick-wall explaining the result computed by GCC on a particular expression.  (My answer was related to `inline` functions; originally the code consisted of two source files and a header.  I've concatenated them into a single source file, not using `inline`.)

#### Code

```
//static inline int somename(int x, int y) { return x + y + 1; }
static int somename(int x, int y) { return x + y + 1; }
extern int nothername(int x, int y);

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("somename(1,2)   = %d\n", somename(1, 2));
    printf("nothername(2,1) = %d\n", nothername(2, 1));
    return 0;
}

int nothername(int x, int y)
{
    printf("x = %d, y = %d, somename(x, y) = %d, cn = %d\n",
           x, y, somename(x, y),  ((y != 0) ? x / y : x));
    int z1 = somename(x, y) +  (y != 0) ? x / y : x;
    int z2 = somename(x, y) + ((y != 0) ? x / y : x);
    printf("z1 = %d, z2 = %d\n", z1, z2);
    return somename(x, y) + (y != 0) ? x / y : x;
}
```

#### Expected output

```
somename(1,2)   = 4
x = 2, y = 1, somename(x, y) = 4, cn = 2
z1 = 6, z2 = 6
nothername(2,1) = 6
```

#### Actual output

```
somename(1,2)   = 4
x = 2, y = 1, somename(x, y) = 4, cn = 2
z1 = 2, z2 = 6
nothername(2,1) = 2
```

### Question:

- Why is `z1` not 6?

#### Environment

This is running on MacOS X 10.6.7.  I've used GCC 4.2.1 provided by Apple as part of XCode 3; I've used GCC 4.6.0 which I compiled.  The original experimentation was related to `inline` functions in C++; equivalent code using `cout` etc produces the same computational results.  I did check that `somename(2, 1)` and `somename(1, 2)` both produce 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The precedence of `?:` is very low, so

```
int z1 = somename(x, y) + (y != 0) ? x / y : x;
```

is interpreted like

```
int z1 = (somename(x, y) + (y != 0)) ? (x / y) : (x);
```

which is `(4 + 1) ? (2 / 1) : 2`, which is 2.

This also explains why adding the parentheses in your computation of `z2` fixed the problem.

Comment: Oh damn!  Of course...I knew it had to be a stupid mental block on my part.  (The trouble was, it was a mental block on my part!)   Thanks.